# Launching copy/paste event not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, clipboard

### **[CODE CONTEXT]**

Hi everyone,

I'm working on an application which  launch copy or paste event by sending keyboard event to press key C and Ctrl.

I'm actually having this method to send Kb event :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

public static void PressKey(Keys key, bool up)
{
    const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
    if (up)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
    }
    else
    {
        keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
    }
}
```

called with :

```
private void launchCopy()
{
    PressKey(Keys.ControlKey, false);
    PressKey(Keys.C, false);
    PressKey(Keys.C, true);
    PressKey(Keys.ControlKey, true);
}
```

and getting the result with the static method :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText()
```

The user has to press other key et using mouse to launch this event, so i'm using SFML to get back the user action using the function `Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key key);` from SFML 2.0.

I've created a infinite loop waiting for a user event, then launch copy and process on the copy data. **This code works fine**
Then I've created another WPF solution with some window and i'm using [NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon).
The main window, after be loaded, create a thread with a method whith the loop (on user event -> launchCopy).

### **[DEBUG]**

When the user press copy event, PressKey method is called, but empty string is returned by `ClipBoard.GetText ()` method.
Using SFML I checked if the key are really pressed

```
  private void PrintState ()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.C)  &&
                      (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.LControl) ||
                       Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.RControl)));
  }

private void launchCopy()
{
    PrintState ();
    PressKey(Keys.ControlKey, false);
    PressKey(Keys.C, false);
    PrintState ();
    PressKey(Keys.C, true);
    PressKey(Keys.ControlKey, true);
    PrintState ();
}
```

And output is :

> False True False

Like it should be...

### **[QUESTIONS]**

Why the shortcut copy simulation doesn't work on this application?
From the working code I :

- put the code in another Thread
- 1 Other thread but same application : WPF windows + NotifyIcon
  library

Is it possible to have a conflit with WPF ?
Or a problem using `PrintState`  method in another thread ?

I'm lost about about to debug this.

Any help or idea would be appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never too late.

My problem was resolved by this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b019991b-3820-4b2e-9137-236506ca5b91/sendinput-to-copypaste-doesnt-work-in-a-new-thread?forum=csharpgeneral), It wasn't the send event, the issue was to retrieve the clipboard data.

Here is the code i used for use the clipboard from another thread :

```
public static class fastClipboard
{
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetClipboardData(uint uFormat);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetClipboardData(uint uFormat, IntPtr hMem);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool IsClipboardFormatAvailable(uint format);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool CloseClipboard();
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GlobalLock(IntPtr hMem);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool GlobalUnlock(IntPtr hMem);

        const uint CF_UNICODETEXT = 13;

        public static bool SetText(string data)
        {
            if (!IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT))
                return false;
            if (!OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero))
                return false;

            var ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(data);
            var res = SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, ptr);
            CloseClipboard();
            if (res != IntPtr.Zero)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public static string GetText()
        {
            if (!IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT))
                return null;
            if (!OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero))
                return null;

            string data = null;
            var hGlobal = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
            if (hGlobal != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var lpwcstr = GlobalLock(hGlobal);
                if (lpwcstr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    data = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(lpwcstr);
                    GlobalUnlock(lpwcstr);
                }
            }
            CloseClipboard();
            return data;
        }
    }
```